# Æ, Ø and Å in Ruby - Why does ("A".."Å").to_a returns double alphabet?

Tags: ruby, string, range

I was playing around in IRB, and found out that:

`("A".."Z").to_a` (of course) returns:

```
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

But `("A".."Å").to_a` returns:

```
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", 
"AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", 
"AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", 
"BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BP", "BQ", 
"BR", "BS", "BT", "BU", "BV", "BW", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", 
...
"ZR", "ZS", "ZT", "ZU", "ZV", "ZW", "ZX", "ZY", "ZZ"]
```

I tried reading about the `to_a` method but couldn't find anything explaining this behaviour.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`("A".."Å")` works similarly to `"A".upto("Å")`. Now there are two things about `String#upto`:

- It uses `String#succ` to get the next value.
- According to [the Ruby specs](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3527c05a8f4e189772cdac17f166bd9626c24661/spec/ruby/core/string/upto_spec.rb#L35-L39) it stops iterating if the size of the current string becomes greater than the size of the final string. This is likely done to avoid infinite ranges.

---

*"Å"* is encoded in two bytes:

```
"Å".bytes # => [195, 133]
```

While *"A"* is encoded in just one:

```
"A".bytes # => [65]
```

---

Lets start iterating:

```
"A".succ # => "B"
"B".succ # => "C"
# ...
"Y".succ # => "Z"
"Z".succ # => "AA"

"AA".succ # => "AB"
# ...
"ZY".succ # => "ZZ"
"ZZ".succ # => "AAA"
```

---

Now *"AAA"* is still "smaller" than *"Å"*:

```
"AAA" < "Å" # => true
```

But it has size of 3 bytes:

```
"AAA".bytes # => [65, 65, 65]
```

Hence as per [the spec](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3527c05a8f4e189772cdac17f166bd9626c24661/spec/ruby/core/string/upto_spec.rb#L35-L39), the range stops here.

Comment: Please correct the wording in _“`("A".."Å")` is shorthand for `"A".upto("Å")`”_ —the former is a range, the latter is the call to the method returning an enumerator instance. They have nothing to do in common, save for calling `#to_a` on both results in the same outcome.

Comment: @mudasobwa, you are correct. I remember this wrong for some reason. Did it create ranges in previous versions?

Comment: I guess so. It quacks as a range :)

Comment: Wauw! Thank you @ndn. I understand now!

Comment: The spec says _"character count"_, not byte count.

Comment: @Stefan, right. But it's reasonable to assume that's what happens under the hood. Otherwise, it would have stopped at `AA`.